# WebDev - Align Logo Text & Nav Bar Using "inline-block"

Tags: html, css

I am new to Web Development, so I'm fiddling around with HTML / CSS. I am curious how I can align a logo / site title text with my navigation bar. I've been reading the SO answers to similar questions for hours now and the answer seems to be utilizing "inline-blocks." But cannot get it to work. Basically I would like "Marston" in the top left corner and my Nav Bar in the top right corner. I would like them aligned vertically. Also the only way I could get the Nav Bar to the right hand side was by creating a huge left margin of 261px - this doesn't seem optimal.

I created a https://jsfiddle.net/19n8v82w/ Fiddle for you guys to look at, although the formatting turns out weird in the small box.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
#page-title {
display: inline-block;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 8px;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 3rem;
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add this styling to your header and remove the margin you will get the layout you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/euxnk73u/

```
header {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. They are now aligned to the same line, but because they have different font sizes - the "Marston" text is vertically center in the header box, but the nav bar is not. How can I fix that?

Comment: @A.Marston For this I would recommend using flex because its much simpler than trying vertical align elements with `inline-block`:

`{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
}` https://jsfiddle.net/pj7mue30/

Comment: That did it, I'll do my research on flex to understand how this works - but thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

add float to nav
Here's my suggestion:

```
nav {
  display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 0;
  float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o3q96gq6/1/

Hope, I understood you correctly and this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This successfully moves the Nav bar to the top right, but neither the "Marston" text nor the nav bar are aligned, nor centered vertically in the header. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @A.Marston well, I would do everything in a slightly different way...
Here's the example of what I would do to make everything match the screen all the time:
https://jsfiddle.net/o3q96gq6/28/